# Inconsistent error format with Meteor Accounts.changePassword

Tags: meteor, error-handling, meteor-accounts

I'm using Meteor 1.8.1 and have found what seems like inconsistent and undocumented behaviour in the errors returned by Accounts.changePassword.

The [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-Error) say that a Meteor error object will include a 'reason' parameter.

But if the attempt to change password fails because the user is not logged in, the error object does not contain 'reason' or 'error', only 'message', which I cannot find in the documentation.

'message' appears to be always returned, despite being undocumented, but is inconsistent in that it includes the error code 403 in the case of incorrect password but not in the case where the user is not logged in.

```
Accounts.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, (error) => {
    console.log('error.message', error.message);
    // not logged in provides message

    console.log('error.reason', error.reason);
    // incorrect password provides reason and message
    if (error) {
        const text = error.reason || error.message;
        console.log('error', text);
    }
       // success
});
```

So my questions are:

- have I missed something? Or is the behaviour really inconsistent and undocumented?
- is there an easy way to get a consistent error message in both cases?
- are there any other 'gotchas' I should test for where Meteor returns an error in a different format again?

Many thanks for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation, `changePassword` method runs only on the client, so you could always check if the user is logged in before attempting to change the password

```
if (!Meteor.user()) {
    return reportError(new Error("Must be logged in to change password."), callback);
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but it doesn't seem to gain me anything over the 'catch-all' code that I've posted above, and it doesn't answer the question about inconsistent error messages?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-changePassword) the description of `Accounts.changePassword` is:

> Change the current user's password. **Must be logged in**.

Therefore, when you try to call this when no user is logged in, it is reasonable for the response to be undefined or inconsistent.  Yes, the docs for a `Meteor.Error` object specify a `reason` property, but `Meteor.Errors` are only thrown when a method wants to return a descriptive error, not when a method is called illegally.

Your user interface code should ensure that a change password form is never shown unless a user is logged in.  If your change password form is only ever shown to logged in users, then you don't need to worry about catching these undefined errors.